# Duvida com exercício de multiplicação de matriz por vetor em C

Tags: c, c++

Preciso fazer um código que usuário informará valores para um vetor de 9 posições, uma matriz de 3x 3. Preciso apresentar os valores do vetor, da matriz e a multiplicação do valor da primeira posição do vetor pela primeira posição da matriz, o segundo valor do vetor pelo segundo valor da matriz, assim por diante, obedecendo a mudança de linha da matriz. segue inicio do código que estou desenvolvendo, preciso de um help para fazer a multiplicação desses valores e para mostra-los

```
int a[9], m[3][3],i;
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    printf("informe um valor para a posição do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &a[0]);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Temos que ler o input do vetor e da matriz e depois faz-se um ciclo na matriz e aumenta-se um contador para obter o índice do vetor e fazer a multiplicação.

```
int a[9], m[3][3], i, x, y;
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    printf("informe um valor para a posição do vetor: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);

}
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        printf("informe um valor para a posição da matriz: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &m[x][y]);
    }
}

printf("Matriz do resultado:\n");
i = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        printf("%d  ", a[i] * m[x][y]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```